# Apache Spark on EC2 - core utilisation

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, rdd

I've been running some Apache Spark programs on EC2. I am wondering how can I see how many cores are being utilised? I have been using large multi core cluster but the performance is hardly better than my laptop.

I have called `rdd1.repartition(sc.defaultParallelism * 3)` on my RDD to try and increase the partitioning - and it increases the number of partitions from a whopping 2 to 6! I have 1 master and 19 slaves - surely this is not right? I was expecting 60 partitions or so.

Comment: what's the ec2 instance type?

Comment: I've used several. At the minute I'm using c3.8xlarge. I've manually repartitioned the RDD to 128 partitions. I was under the impression that 2-3 x the number of clusters was the ideal; however, 1 partition per core is working quicker. Do you know why it seems to default to 2? Even on my Mac (8 cores) it was only partitioning an RDD in 2.

Comment: you have 20 instances of EC2 running?

Comment: I've had 19 slaves and 1 master. However, now I am using 4 slaves and 1 master.

Comment: did you make sure on your aws console that all your instances are in the same cluster?

Comment: Yes they are. I have manually set the number of partitions to 3 * the number of cores. I was under the impression that `sc.defaultParallelism` would give me the number of cores in my cluster; however, it always returns 2.

Comment: Just tested it again. Launched another 20 node cluster; `sc.defaultParallelism` returns 2. Instance type: t2.medium - which have 2 cores per instance. It would seem the `sc.defaultParallelism` is returning the number of cores for just 1 node, perhaps the master node.

Comment: What do you see on the [master UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually)? It should be easy to tell if all your slaves have registered with the master correctly. If not, that's why you wouldn't see the number of cores you are expecting. If you are having trouble setting up a Spark cluster on EC2, it might be better to start off with [spark-ec2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html), which will take care of everything for you as far as basic setup.

Comment: I've been using spark-ec2 and all the clusters are visible on the master UI. However, calling `sc.defaultParallelism` only ever gives 2. Clearly, something is going awry